# Uploading 500 apps on Android Market with Different Languages

Tags: android, localization, google-play

I have 100 applications(very similar ones) running on Android Market with English Language, i would like to know if i can change the language of these apps and republish with new Package(and as a new app) without any problems.

Probably we will need to change it to 5 or more languages(spanish, korean, french, germany, etc), so it will be 500 new apps all over the market.

Our apps work with images, we will translate small things(just the help screen, menu, title and icon)

Will this be considered as spam or repetitive content?

Comment: You shouldn't be doing this, instead use the alternative resources approach, providing a different folder with values for your curent applications. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html

Comment: I don't know. But I would see it as spam, I mean you're uploading 100 application(that as you say are similar) and change only the language.

Comment: It seem like someone trying to earn a quick $$$$

Answer (score 4):

Why not just localize the strings and other resources in your apps? Then you'll have just one APK for all the languages, and the correct language will be used depending on the user's locale. See [developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html#using-framework](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html#using-framework) for the details on how to do it.

You really shouldn't do what you're proposing in your question. Not only it will make the maintenance of your apps a nightmare, but also Google may very well have an issue with so many copies of the same app.

Comment: No one can stop you from shooting yourself in the foot by doing this, we can just suggest the proper way to do things :) Are you using source control? Your approach seems to suggest a large number of branches for each language; if that's the case, how are you going to fix bugs? The merging of changes is sure to keep you busy for a long time. It's yet another reason not to go with that approach.

Comment: I couldn't immediately find any rule against that, but I wouldn't be surprised if Google removes those apps as duplicate... I guess you'll have to try it and see what happens.

Comment: @user1247870: "We are going to release in another languages, cause we can reach more users and consecutively get more ads on our adnetworks" -- so you are admitting that you are a spammer, gaming the Android Market and harming the ecosystem for your own benefit.